# Importing config table with c# within BIML

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, ssis, biml

Im working with *c#* within *BIML* in *SSIS*. My question is mainly on the following Snippet. Main idea is to import a Config table for a dynamic staging process in SSIS.

**Code Snippet**

```
<# var tables = 
 ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(sourceConnection.ConnectionString, "SELECT 
 * FROM ImportTable").Rows.OfType<System.Data.DataRow>().Select(r => 
 r[0].ToString()); #>
```

It throws following **Error**:

**Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataRow'**.

**First Question:** I have to say that I don't really understand what is happening there. It seems like that the program is looking for the DataType of the original DataTable on an SQL Database. Can somebody explain what is happening here and has a clue how to fix the Error?

**Second Question:** What is happening in the last part of the snippet?

```
Select(r => r[0].ToString());
```

My first guess was that it Selects all rows greater or equal to the first row in the table and converts it to a string?

**My Full Code**:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.OleDb" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>

<#@ template language="C#" tier="2" #>


<# var sourceConnection = 
 (AstDbConnectionNode)RootNode.Connections["Source"]; #>
<# var importedSchema = sourceConnection.ImportDB("", "", 
 ImportOptions.ExcludeForeignKey | ImportOptions.ExcludeColumnDefault | 
 ImportOptions.ExcludeViews); #>
<# var tables = 
 ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(sourceConnection.ConnectionString, "SELECT 
 * FROM ImportTable").Rows.OfType<System.Data.DataRow>().Select(r => 
 r[0].ToString()); #>


<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Packages>
***BIML-Code***
</Packages>
</Biml>
```